# how to limit goroutine

Tags: go, google-api, gmail-api, goroutine

I'm developing a gmail client based on google api.

I have a list of labels obtained through this call

```
r, err := s.gClient.Service.Users.Labels.List(s.gClient.User).Do()
```

Then, for every label I need to get details

```
for _, l := range r.Labels {
    d, err := s.gClient.Service.Users.Labels.Get(s.gClient.User, l.Id).Do()
}
```

I'd like to handle the loop in a more powerful way so I have implemented a goroutine in the loop:

```
ch := make(chan label.Label)

for _, l := range r.Labels {

    go func(gmailLabels *gmailclient.Label, gClient *gmail.Client, ch chan<- label.Label) {

        d, err := s.gClient.Service.Users.Labels.Get(s.gClient.User, l.Id).Do()

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        // Performs some operation with the label `d`
        preparedLabel := ....

        ch <- preparedLabel

    }(l, s.gClient, ch)
}

for i := 0; i < len(r.Labels); i++ {
    lab := <-ch
    fmt.Printf("Processed %v\n", lab.LabelID)
}
```

The problem with this code is that gmail api has a rate limit, so, I get this error:

```
panic: googleapi: Error 429: Too many concurrent requests for user, rateLimitExceeded
```

What is  the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about only starting e.g. 10 goroutines and pass the values in from one for loop in another go routine. The channels have a small buffer to decrease synchronisation time.

```
chIn := make(chan label.Label, 20)
chOut := make(chan label.Label, 20)

for i:=0;i<10;i++ {
    go func(gClient *gmail.Client, chIn chan label.Label, chOut chan<- label.Label) {

        for gmailLabels := range chIn {
            d, err := s.gClient.Service.Users.Labels.Get(s.gClient.User, l.Id).Do()

            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            // Performs some operation with the label `d`
            preparedLabel := ....

            chOut <- preparedLabel

        }

    }(s.gClient, chIn, chOut)

}

go func(chIn chan label.Label) {
    defer close(chIn)
    for _, l := range r.Labels {
        chIn <- l
    }
}(chIn)

for i := 0; i < len(r.Labels); i++ {
    lab := <-chOut
    fmt.Printf("Processed %v\n", lab.LabelID)
}
```

EDIT:

Here a [playground sample](https://play.golang.org/p/R4b296QOrk).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but I don't understand how can I go ahead... the program, blocks after elaborating 10 labels

Comment: Ops sorry, I had forgotten the "for gmailLabels := range chIn {" in first goroutine. Now it process all the labels but I get this error:
panic: runtime error: index out of range [recovered]
 panic: runtime error: index out of range

Comment: Sorry but I'm sleeping: D
Actually everything works very well! However there are two things that I don't understand 1) what do you mean with "The channels have a small buffer to decrease synchronisation time." 2) why do you have created the two buffers with size of 20?

Comment: Size 20 of the channels is the 'small buffer'. If you have an unbuffered channel, the sending/receiving side has to wait for the other side to receive/send. If you have buffers, you eliminate some waiting time. Only if the buffer is full, the sending side has to wait and if the buffer is empty the receiving side has to wait.

Comment: Thanks, you were very clear. I tried to raise the value in the loop: "for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {". Still works well and it takes less time

Comment: Perfect. Yes, you can play around with how many go routines you start and also with the buffer sizes. If you use 50 goroutines I suggest you increase the buffers to be at least as large.